# Cannot execute sql insert into .mdb file using ACE driver. Works with .accdb file

Tags: visual-c++, ms-access, ado, adox

I am using ACE database driver. I am creating access database using ADOX and am trying to insert the data using SQL command. When the filename is using .mdb extension it doesn't works while it works when using .accdb.   I am using the x64 ace driver

```
    //create new database
PMString connectString("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=");
connectString += getFileName().c_str();
ADOX::_CatalogPtr pCatalog(__uuidof(ADOX::Catalog));
try{
    pCatalog->Create(connectString.c_str());
}catch( _com_error &e){
    throw dymexexception("Error creating table");
}


    //init connection
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
if (FAILED(hr))
    throw dymexexception("Failed to initialize database");
hr = pConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
if (FAILED(hr))
    throw dymexexception("Failed to initialize database");
hr = pConnection->Open(connectString.c_str(),"","",0);
if(FAILED(hr))
    throw dymexexception("Failed to initialize database");
```

and this is the inserting part

```
        //build sql insert query and execute it
    queryString = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES(";
    for(int i=0;i<fieldValues.size();i++)
    {
        if(i>0)
            queryString += ",";
        queryString += fieldValues[i];
    }
    queryString += ")";
    executeSqlCmd(pCommand,queryString);
```

Where this is the executeSqlCmd function

```
AdoNS::_RecordsetPtr ResultDatabase::executeSqlCmd(AdoNS::_CommandPtr pCommand,      PMString queryString)
{
pCommand->CommandText = (_bstr_t) queryString.c_str();
return pCommand->Execute(NULL,NULL,NULL);
}
```

Any feedback?